# *nix window manager that places window list on window title bar?

Tags: unix, window-manager

Like this... looks really kind of cool, so I'm wondering what it might be.

[image: Qtpfsgui screenshot on a Unix-like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like the Keramik theme from [KWin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KWin):

[image]

Note that the button placing can be adjusted, and these are different versions.

Comment: Can all Kwin themes do that? Are there any GNOME compatible window managers/decorators that can do that?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. And I don't know of one for GNOME unfortunately, but someone on the GNOME-look forums may know: http://gnome-look.org/comments/discussion.php